# How to resolve CORS error for Rest API when my target is dynamy

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, cors

I am trying to create Rest Response simulator (like postman) using angular and node js. Whenever I tried to send a request it's giving me CORS ( cross origin resource sharing) error. 
I found using proxy.config resolves this issue where we give the host in target. But in my case the URL s are dynamic. I cannot define all the targets in proxy.config file. 
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your server script

```
app.all("/api/*", function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization,   Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
    return next();
});
```

If you are using angular with springboot you just add the following line before the controller definition

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200",allowedHeaders="*")
```

For example:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200",allowedHeaders="*")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountServiceImpl accountService;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String startPage(){
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

It will resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok, I am not using spring boot. It's just angular using httpclient methods. And I have tried 'Access-control-Allow-Origin' header as well.